# Magento not showing products while saving in backend

Tags: magento

I have a small problem with my Magento 1.5

The products is showing ok in the frontend, but on open a product in backend and press Save or Save and Continue, the frontend is not showing nothing.

I think that here is a problem with Index Management.

What can i do to no reindex the hole category or the hole database on save product ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the behavior of the index to not update on every product change, and only do it manually (i.e. via cronjob)

You can change that in the admin area at System / Index Management. Select the Product Index and choose "Change index mode" in the dropdown.